# Should it be possible to gain reputation on comments, or to mark them as "accepted answer"?

Tags: discussion, comments, reputation

Several times I answered a question through comments (ex. link to solution) because I didn't want to spam one-liner answers. See for example [Hide x-axis labels with Xlsxwriter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69402254/hide-x-axis-labels-with-xlsxwriter?noredirect=1#comment122668273_69402254)

Does it make sense to add an option to mark a comment as an accepted "answer" and also give reputation to it? Or should I really add this one-liner as an answer?

Comment: I think the common consensus is that only questions for clarification should go into comments and that any comment can be deleted at any time for any reason. So answers should go into the Answer-box. Just a one-liner with a link is however not considered an Answer, and will be deleted, see [When to flag an answer as “not an answer”](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265552/when-to-flag-an-answer-as-not-an-answer)

Comment: "does it make sense to add an option to mark a comment as an accepted "answer" and also give reputation to it?" No, it doesn't, for multiple reasons. Note that comments are not for [writing answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Flesh it out into an answer instead (maybe add an explanation or example, so its more useful to future users). And yes, I know that I'm answering your question in a comment :)

Comment: @Scratte "Just a one-liner with a link is however not considered an Answer" that's at least imprecise, if not incorrect. See the post you link to for the definition of a link-only answer that is flaggable as NAA.

Comment: I dont see the point of turning the comment functionality into answers. especially when they are meant to be temporary.  If it can be an answer why not make it one?

Comment: @JeanneDark Sure.. if there is an Answer there in the one-liner. But if it only consists of the link, then.. it's not an Answer. Which is the impression I got from the Question here.

Comment: @Scratte See the [OP's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69402254/hide-x-axis-labels-with-xlsxwriter?noredirect=1#comment122668201_69402254) on the question. Turned into an answer it wouldn't be link-only.

Comment: @JeanneDark No, it wouldn't. I generally advocate for **not** deleting such posted as Answers, but they tend to go missing in the Low Quality Posts queue. Perhaps writing an actual Answer with explanations would be best for the poster.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If the question is worth answering with more than a link, then users better spend time posting an actual answer with **more than a link**.

One-liners are not necessarily bad, but many times they are a sign that either the question was low-quality to begin with, or that a better answer was possible.

We shouldn't encourage posting more of these comments. We want quality answers, not users gaining rep for comments.

In some cases, very short answers are perfectly fine though. The question is not a dupe, is not a typo... and yet it can be fully answered with a very short answer. In those cases go ahead and post the answer (as long as the very short answer is not just a link, because we [do not consider](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265553/11407695) those to be answers around here).

---

In the example you posted, the comment you posted wouldn't qualify as "link-only" answer if posted as such:

> A quick look in the documentation helps ;) : [xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/chart.html](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/chart.html) -> method chart.set_x_axis({'visible': False})

Wouldn't be a **great** answer, but would not be subject to deletion as "not an answer".

However, when answering a question is that easy, it's worth considering if the question couldn't have been posted already, and if it wouldn't be better to close it as a duplicate. In this example, I believe the question could be a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30897097/1426539), or maybe [this other one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35037689/how-to-create-chart-with-xlsxwriter-with-no-horizontal-value-axis). So I don't think posting an answer is the best course of action, but flagging for closure would.

Comment: In this case the comment also contained the code for solving the issue `chart.set_x_axis({'visible': False})` and not only the link, so it would be an actual answer if posted as such, not link-only.

Comment: I never said it would be link-only, @user000001. I was answering the general question, not dealing with that comment specifically. No idea if that comment is worth keeping as an answer, or if the question is any good.

Comment: Just checked more carefully, @user000001. Indeed, not link-only. But the question appears to be a duplicate, unless I'm mistaken.

Answer (score 5):

No. If it makes sense to *accept* as an answer, it makes sense to *post* as an answer.

Comment: ... I don't like what you're proving here, a one-liner can be a complete answer :)